# Maze Solver in Haskell - Determine if maze is unsolvable

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

I have been recently trying to create a maze-solver in Haskell and I have managed to piece together a mostly working algorithm. However I am lost as to how to determine if a given maze is impossible to solve.

```
solveMazeQuickly :: Maze -> Place -> Place -> Path
solveMazeQuickly maze start target = fastSolveMazeIter maze target [(start, [])] [start] -- last is the elem of visited nodes along with its paths

fastSolveMazeIter :: Maze -> Place -> [(Place, Path)] -> [Place] -> Path
fastSolveMazeIter maze target (x:xs) visited -- last argument is the list of visited places
 | (tenatives == []) && (length (x:xs) == length (visited)) = error "unsolvable maze"
 | currentPos == target = pathPos -- return the path if we're already there
 | otherwise = fastSolveMazeIter maze target (xs++tenatives) (visited++(map fst tenatives))
   where currentPos = fst x -- current position
         pathPos = snd x -- the path to current position
         tenatives = scan currentPos pathPos -- the 'successful' tried paths
         try pos curPath d
          | ((hasWall maze pos d) == False) && ((nextPos `elem` visited) == False) = [(nextPos, curPath++[d])] -- disregard visited positions
          | otherwise = []
            where nextPos = move d pos
         scan pos curPath = (try pos curPath N) ++ (try pos curPath S) ++ (try pos curPath E) ++ (try pos curPath W) -- try the four directions
```

The co-ordinate system is based on each 'squares' of the maze. Each position has walls that can be on its 4 sides, and this information is stored inside the `Maze` datatype.

The algorithm keeps track of the places that it has visited, as well as storing a list of the places that it can access, together with the path to that point from the start.

Thus far, I have attempted to take into account for an unsolvable maze with a condition that if the visited positions are equal in size to the accessible positions, with no possible way to continue the solution (`tentative == []`), then the maze is unsolvable. However that does not seem to do the trick.

When attempting to solve the following impossible maze

```
+--+--+--+
|     |  |
+  +  +--+
|  |     |
+  +--+  +
|        |
+--+--+--+
```

Haskell returns "Maze Practical\Main.lhs:(88,3)-(99,118): Non-exhaustive patterns in function fastSolveMazeIter" instead of the intended error message.

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to do the trick?

Comment: As of now, your question is not clear. Please, include the exact error you're getting and the test case that your code fails. "Doesn't seem to do the trick" is not really helpful.

Comment: @kraskevich Thank you for replying. I have updated the question with the error message & test case.

Comment: Flood fill ...?

Comment: fastSolveMazeIter includes the pattern (x:xs) in its argument list. What should happen if the argument is empty?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Thank you very much. The algorithm is supposed to terminate at the empty list but I forgot to consider that x:xs cannot possibility be empty.

Comment: @PaulJohnson That should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastSolveMazeIter includes the pattern (x:xs) in its argument list. What should happen if the argument is empty?